# Change preset settings in OS X print dialog (Canon iR-ADV 2030i)

Tags: macos, printing, canon

I'm using OS X 10.9. I need to change some of the advanced printer settings in the presets dialog (the printer is Canon ImageRunner Advance 2030i). In this case I'd like to change the 'print style' setting under 'finishing' but I have no clue what to do to make the actual change happen. I tried clicking in combination with various keys but the setting still seems to be displayed as read-only (see screenshot). What should I do?

[image: The dialog]

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to do this via the UI but you can go to `~/Library/Preferences` and look for `com.apple.print.custompresets.forprinter.*.plist` (where `*` stands for your printer name). The file only exists if you created a custom preset.

You can open the `plist` with Xcode and edit all printer settings.